# Escape Velocity (Rail gun, acceleration, weight)

Tags: newtonian-gravity, escape-velocity

I'm not so technical and not very good with physics, but have some idea based on observation and I believe it is doable.

As everyone know also this subject was repeated many times in here, 
Sending stuff to space is very expensive. But what if there is an easy way to do that only if we would think out side the box.

So lets imagine (I do not want to go into many details where did I take it from)...

An object of mass 100 kg which is on track isn't affected by gravity. I mean, it does not fall or move, unless it's touched. The only problem is air drag. So, how much energy and what would be the length of the track required to attain escape velocity? The track would be flat with a slide up at (what would be the angle of it?) the end so that the object would reach safe orbit where it would not fall back? I believe object would have to be heat resistant. Is that right?  What type of engine (cheapest way) would be applied to accelerate such object? I believe people would not be able to travel inside as G force would be to big? Please describe it in simpler language, as English is not my native.

Comment: what do you mean by *"it does not have gravity"*. Are you assuming the earth doesn't apply a gravitational force on it?

Comment: see below explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you are asking about the efficient way to gain escape velocity in the given situation. This is what I think of as a layman's way and what I know...

$\text{What is this escape velocity?}$

According what I have studied till now, escape velocity is the minimum initial velocity required to get out of the gravitational field of an object like planet's in case of earth I think which is $11.2\ km/s$. Now it is not  possible to attain such high acceleration with today's technology and even if you have such powerful engine the ship your are sending will just rip off here on the first place due to such high acceleration.

$\text{What you've asked?}$

> Object 100 kg which is on track and it does not have gravity, mean it does not fall nether move unless touched then it moves but the only hindrance it has is air. so how much energy and what would be the length of the track required to escape velocity ? track would be flat with a slide up at ( what recommended degree)the end so the object would reach safe orbit where it would not fall? I believe object would have to be heat resistant ? is that correct? What type of engine ( cheapest way) would be applied to accelerate such object? I believe people would not be able to travel inside as G force would be to big?

So you are saying that the object or ship or whatever device you are using don't feel gravity, so the question of escape velocity is eliminated here itself. However if it is only experiencing the resistance due to the air so it will need very little power to go out in the space (which would have been very profitable). Since there is no gravity working, so you can have your track setup at ant angle you want (perpendicular to the earth will be appreciated).

Well if there is  no gravity so don't need to go at soo high speed so there will not much resistance due to air to burn you down. You can use any engine you want all will do up to your condition's in this question

Hmm if you try to accelerate any ship at that high velocity even if ship is strong enough there will be no driver or passenger left in the ship as they would suffer a $G$ force of $1120g$ Which I think is not a good number at all. I hope you got it.

Comment: I think you should have a conversation with Neil Armstrong about whether we have the technology for a human to reach escape velocity safely.

Comment: is there any thing wrong that i don't know and i said bt mistake

Answer (score 0):

OK Guys thanks for explanation I will give you an example how I thought about this...Probably I will never be able to build such track, nether will have resources for IT. Unless I would find bunch of people that would like to do that with resources. So here it is how I came up with it... Please you tube Quantum Levitation and see how object behave It looks like it would not have gravitation at all...so It could be used to give speed to an object on track to  reach 13 km / s as I think in answer is slight mistake. and there is no need to get so much energy which would be extremely efficient.Please let me know what do you think about it and if it doable ! Enjoy the brainstorms !

Comment: i have not mistaken at what i said but the fact i said it in wrong place i think, and yes those quantum levitation's video were good but still it can't be used for transporting heavy load's under the influence of gravity i think, well if had the resource then i could have jumped in your pool cause i alway's think of doing stuff like these and look people who can support my idea